# Javascript - Explain the difference between the deletion methods (given in the description)

Tags: javascript

what's the difference between the two following methods when deleting a an element from html's body? I tried playing around and made up the first line of code and it works fine. Are there situations it won't work? I also don't get why we need to call the parentNode in the second line..

```
document.body.removeChild(resetButton);

resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);
```

here's the full code for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var resetButton = document.createElement('button');
  resetButton.textContent = 'Start new game';
  document.body.appendChild(resetButton);

  //document.body.removeChild(resetButton);
  //resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't work when *resetButton* is not a direct children of *body*. However i would still take method 3:

```
resetButton.remove();
```